# Can we Install ipa file on unknown UDID iOS Device?

Tags: ios, xcode

Apple developer site is down. So I can't add the new UDIDs in my developer account. But now I have to install the app on my all iOS devices (UDIDs not added in developer account). So can anyone tell me how to install the apps on iOS devices without adding UDID? I have searched a lot and tried some methods but failed. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: If someone can share you an enterprise developer account distribution cert + private key + in-house provisioning profile then you can get your wish come true. Else, nothing but wait for Apple to make the dev portal online.

Comment: Thanks for the reply amar . Can you tell me what do you mean by In house provisioning profile ?.

Comment: The enterprise account allows distributing apps in house as-in within the organisation/enterprise. Importance of that profile is it installs on any device without adding the UDID.

Answer (score 3):

There is no legal way to do that, unless you distribute under the Enterprise license.

**Edit:** for more info about Enterprise license check:

[iOS developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/)

[Support center](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)

Comment: Please note, that Enterprise terms of service prohibit you from installing your app on devices outside your company.

Answer (score 1):

No i don't think there is way to Install ipa file on unknown UDID ios Device.